# How can I sort the float list

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, quantitative-finance

I was writing this code for downloading the stock data and finding the percentage change in the price over the given time span. After doing all the calculations, retrievals, and storing the final data in a list, I wanted to sort the change list, but I was unable to do so. Please help me!

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import numpy as np

change=[]
today = date.today()
tickers = ['^GSPC', 'AAPL', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', 'MS', 'JPM']
for tick in tickers:
  start_date = '2012-01-01'
  end_date = today
  dataset = data.DataReader(tickers, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
  close=dataset['Close']
  close_new=close.shift(1)
  close2=close-close_new
  close3=close2.dropna()
  u=close.loc['2012-01-04',tick]
  v=close.loc['2020-06-22',tick]
  c=((v-u)/u)*100
  change.append(c)
print(change.sort())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) method, modifies the list **in-place** (and returns `None`). Usually it’s less convenient than `sorted()` - but if you don’t need the original list, it’s slightly more efficient. Anyway, you can use [`sorted`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sorted.asp):

```
print(sorted(change))
```

or [`numpy.sort`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
print(np.sort(change))
```

Answer (score 1):

`sort()` function does not return anything. So please switch your last line to following 2 lines:

```
change.sort()
print(change)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sorted` if you want to get a new sorted list.

```py
print(sorted(change))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can basically use `sorted()`
If you just wanna sort it to print you can make that

```
print(sorted(change)) # Or whatever your list name
```

Or you can re-define the variable if you wanna reuse the list

```
change = sorted(change)
```